# Does anyone knows about details of L2 cache structure of NVIDIA Kepler GPUs(Mapping function, Replacement policy, Associativity)?

Tags: caching, gpu

I need the detail information about L2 caches of NVIDIA Kepler GPUs. I know the size (e.g. 512KB on GT740M GPU) and block size (32B) of the cache. I tried to capture the associativity, replacement policy, and more importantly, the mapping function (from global address to cache line), by a sample kernel and profiling the read hit ratio by nvprof profiler. I realized that mapping is not modulo operation. Is there any trick to find out what cache line a given global address is mapped to? can anyone help me?

Answer (score 2):

Just as @Dmitri Budnikov memtioned, cache information is not public available.

Some researchers are working on this problem, and [This Paper](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1509.02308.pdf) give us some insights on the memory hierarchy of GPU architecture.

Their findings on L2 cache can be summarized as below:

1. The replacement policy of the L2 cache is not LRU;
2. The L2 cache line size is 32 bytes;
3. The data mapping is sophisticated and not conventional bits-defined;
4. A hardware-level pre-fetching mechanism from the DRAM to the L2 data cache is found on fermi, Kepler and Maxwell architecture.

The benchmarks they developed can be found [here](http://www.comp.hkbu.edu.hk/~chxw/gpu_benchmark.html#l2_cache).